# Curl post /curl: no URL specified

Tags: curl, payload

I'm stuck with a cURL post command:
To interact with a PTZ camera, through its API, I can use payloads.
I use a command that works and return a token (the first one below).
But, when I want to command the device with ptzctrl for example, it systematicaly returns `curl: no URL specified!`

```
#!/bin/bash
vartoken=`curl -i -s -k -X $'POST' --data-binary $'[{\"cmd\":\"Login\",\"action\":0,\"param\":{\"User\":{\"userName\":\"my_username\",\"password\":\"my_password\"}}}]' $'http://192.168.x.xxx:yyyy/cgi-bin/api.cgi?cmd=Login&token=null' | grep name |sed -r 's/(.*: \")(.*)(\".*)/\2/g'`
echo $vartoken
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -g -v -k -X $'POST' --data-binary $'[{\"cmd\":\"PtzCtrl\",\"action\":0,\"param\":{\"channel\":0,\"op\":\"ToPos\",\"speed\":32,\"id\":2}}]'$"http://192.168.x.xxx:yyyy/cgi-bin/api.cgi?cmd=PtzCtrl&token=${vartoken}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution given on another post, I correct it there:
I missed the space before $"http...
the new request is now:

`curl -g -v -k -X $'POST' --data-binary $'[{\"cmd\":\"PtzCtrl\",\"action\":0,\"param\":{\"channel\":0,\"op\":\"ToPos\",\"speed\":32,\"id\":2}}]' $"http://192.168.x.xxx:yyyy/cgi-bin/api.cgi?cmd=PtzCtrl&token=${vartoken}"`

Thanks for reading.

cheers, djo